# AngularJS expression filter with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I am trying to display the distance in miles, between two coordinates.

Below is the filter. I need to pass four arguments: Start Latitude 1, Finish Longitude 1, Start Latitude 2, Finish Longitude 2 and Unit (Nautical Miles).

```
app.filter('distanceFrom', function() {

  return function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
  };

});
```

Using this expression in the view I am trying to pass the required arguments:

```
{{ distanceFromMiles | distanceFrom: 53.800043:-1.546669:53.8007554:-1.5490773999999874:106.85937254260821:N}}
```

However on the page the expression is Null. Any ideas on how I can get the above filter working would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need to pass the final paramater unit in as a string with quotes, like this 'N'

Comment: Thanks for the idea Steven but unfortunately still getting null with this code `{{ distanceFromMiles | distanceFrom: 53.800043:-1.546669:53.8007554:-1.5490773999999874:106.85937254260821:'N'}} `

Comment: Is the Filter getting called when you put a breakpoint in the Filter function?

Comment: Yes it writes to the console when I load the page. I just noticed that distanceFromMiles wasn't defined, so when I create an empty scope variable called distanceFromMiles I now get the following as the result - rather than Null:

106.85937254260821

This is the last longitude coordinate. It's still wrong as it should display the distance between the two coordinates. Thanks again for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first variable in the filter function will get the filter expression(distanceFromMiles) not the latitude

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/views-and-directives.html